# How do I solve this non linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I will like to know how to solve this non linear equation.
$$\frac{\tan 6a}{\tan 2a}=\frac{3}{2}$$
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and [how to use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please, Is there anything you didn't understand in my question? I just want to solve the equation above.

Answer (score 1):

Using the angle addition formula for $\tan(\theta + 2 \theta)$, $\tan 3 \theta = \frac{3 \tan \theta - \tan^3 \theta}{1 - 3 \tan^2 \theta}$. Thus $\frac{\tan 3 \theta}{\tan \theta} = \frac{3 - \tan^2 \theta}{1 - 3 \tan^2 \theta} = \frac{2}{3}$ which is now a quadratic equation in terms of $\tan \theta$, where $\theta = 2a$.

Comment: Please what is Tan@?

Comment: You need to show some work of your own. It is better for your problem-solving skills to try some things yourself.